# How to open a custom protocol url with urllib?

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension, urllib, network-protocols, momentum

I use chrome [Momentum](https://momentumdash.com/) extension to customize my browser new tab and would like to write a python script to get its daily dashboard wallpaper

By now I know I can reach desired page through the url

```
chrome-extension://laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca/dashboard.html
```

However, when I try to call `urllib.request.urlopen` with this url the following error is raised:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: chrome-extension>
```

Is possible to include custom protocols to be open by `urllib`?

Or would there be another way to get page html result?

Answer (score 0):

If the file exists locally and not on the web then using urllib won't do you much good since it's not a URL.

use webbrowser lib instead and provide a path to your file:

```py
    def auto_open():
        """
        This method takes the absolute path to the html file and opens it directly in the browser.
        """
        html_page = 'path/to/your/file'
        # open in a new tab.
        new = 2
        webbrowser.open(html_page, new=new)
```